# A change of coordinates such that the first entries on a finite set become distinct

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a homework problem from algebraic geometry, and my solution revolves around the following proposition which I haven't been able to prove.

> Let $k$ be an infinite field. Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^2_k$ be a finite subset. View $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ as a $k$-vector space. Then there exists some $n$ such that the linear transformation $$ T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ has the property that $|\pi_1(T(X))| = |X|$

The proposition states, informally, that given a finite collection in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$, we can find a change of coordinates such that all the first coordinates of our collection under the transformation will be distinct.

Are there any hints or easy ways to see that this might be true?

I should note that this holds trivially if $X$ already has the property that the first coordinates are distinct. We simply take $n = 0$. Beyond that, I'm stuck. Also, there is no special reason I picked $T$ in this case. We could generalize it to any invertible $T$. I just have a feeling that this invertible transformation will do the trick for some $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pair of distinct points $x_1,x_2\in X$, there exists at most one $n$ such that $\pi_1(T(x_1))=\pi_1(T(x_2))$. There are only finitely many such pairs, but infinitely many available choices for $n$.

Comment: Duh!! Thank you, thank you.